# Size of error when approximating $\pi$ using Buffon's needle

Tags: probability, statistics

A friend of mine wrote a pet program to find the value of $\pi$ using one of the algorithms which exploit random values, like Buffon's needle. He complained that after using 10,000 random number he reached a lousy approximation, something like 3.15. I answered that it should have been expected: my heuristics started with the Central Limit Theorem and noticed that a standard deviation is the square root of the number of samples, so the number of significant digits found should roughly be half the number of digits of the sample. Indeed he tried with 100,000,000 samples and obtained approximately 3.14162.

My question: is there a way to formalize how many expected significant digits may be typically found while running such an experiment?

Comment: Nothing general can be said: you have to know which algorithm is used. Nevertherless, for very basic algorithms, a rule of thumb (which has statistical rationale) is that you have (very roughly) to multiply by 100 the number of experiments in order to gain an order of magnitude (i.e., a new decimal). For example with $100^5=10^{10}$  experiments, you can expect around 5 significant digits.

Comment: The crux of the problem is that the standard deviation of the sample mean is proportional to $1/\sqrt{n}$, so to improve your estimate by a factor of 10, you must increase the sample size by a factor of 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buffon's needle is one of the least efficient ways to approximate $\pi$, since the error in approximation is proportional to $1/\sqrt n$, where $n$ is the number of tries. This is the case whenever you perform sampling from a large 'population' to estimate some kind of 'success' rate.

We can calculate the expected error in approximating $\pi$ when dropping Buffon's needle $n$ times onto a plane ruled with parallel lines. Suppose we obtain $X$ crossings this way. Assume, as in the standard formulation of the problem, the needle length equals the spacing of the parallel lines. Then the probability that a dropped needle crosses a line is $\frac2\pi$, hence $X$ has binomial$(n,p)$ distribution with $p:=\frac2\pi$. By the central limit theorem (or the normal approximation to the binomial), the random variable
$$
Y:=\frac X{2n}$$
has approximately normal distribution with mean $$ E(Y)=\frac{np}{2n}=\frac1\pi$$ and variance $$\operatorname{Var}(Y)=\frac{p(1-p)}{4n}=\frac{\frac2\pi(1-\frac2\pi)}{4n}.$$
Notice that $1/Y$ approximates $\pi$. To estimate the error in this approximation we compute
$$
\frac1Y-\pi=\frac\pi Y\left(\frac1\pi-Y\right)\approx\pi^2\left(\frac1\pi-Y\right).
$$
The expected error in estimating $\pi$ with $1/Y$ is therefore
$$
\begin{align}
E\left | \frac1Y -\pi\right|&\approx\pi^2 E\left|Y-\frac1\pi\right|\\
&\stackrel{(*)}=\pi^2\sqrt{\frac{\frac2\pi(1-\frac2\pi)}{4n}}\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\\
&=\frac{\pi\sqrt{1-\frac2\pi}}{\sqrt n},
\end{align}
$$
where in step (*) we use the formula $E(|Z|)=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}$ for a standard normal variable $Z$. When $n=100,000,000$ the expected error amounts to about $2\times 10^{-4}$.

You can use a similar argument to calculate the number of drops needed to achieve a specified amount of error (say, with probability exceeding $1-\alpha$). It takes quite a bit of effort to achieve even a small improvement in accuracy.

Comment: I understood that my friend was more interested in a proof-of-concept (that is, to see if actually a random process would converge to $\pi$) than in an actual way to compute it.

Comment: @mau The "Buffon process" for estimating $\pi$ will certainly do, since $Y$ converges almost surely to $1/\pi$ as $n\to\infty$ by the law of large numbers, and so $1/Y$ will converge to $\pi$ almost surely. The above discussion quantifies how fast -- or slowly! -- this convergence takes place. The $1/\sqrt n$ rate of convergence applies to any sequence of repeated trials where the probability of success per trial depends on $\pi$.

Comment: Can you please explain in more details the (*) argument: I cant see why $\pi^2 E(Y- 1/\pi)$ gives the next step.

Comment: @OlePetersen  This follows from the previous observation that $Y$ has approximately normal distribution with mean $\mu:=\frac1\pi$ and variance $\sigma^2:=\frac{\frac2\pi(1-\frac2\pi)}{4n}$. Therefore $\frac{Y-\mu}\sigma\approx Z$ which implies $E|Y-\mu|\approx \sigma E|Z|$.

Comment: Thanks. How do we know that $E(Z)  = (\frac{2}{\pi})^{0.5} $ ?

Comment: @OlePetersen See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1907923/215011 . To calculate the integral, use the substitution $u:=y^2/2$.